# Polymer data binding across elements not working in Chrome dev / canary

Tags: polymer

I've been happily developing an app in Polymer. All is going well, but some fairly basic stuff isn't working in Chrome Dev and Chrome Canary, is this expected?

Here's a reduction of what I'm seeing [[codepen to try it out yourself](http://codepen.io/rictic/pen/Jypta/?editors=100)]:

```
<script src="http://www.polymer-project.org/platform.js"></script></script>
<link rel="import" href="http://www.polymer-project.org/components/polymer/polymer.html">

<my-app></my-app>

<polymer-element name='my-app'>
  <template>
    <my-processor input='{{input}}' output='{{output}}'>
    <input value='{{input}}'> <br>
    Input: {{input}} <br>
    Processed: {{output}} 
  </template>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-app', { 'input': 'hello world', });
  </script>
</polymer-element>

<polymer-element name='my-processor' attributes='input output'>
  <script>
    Polymer('my-processor', {
      inputChanged: function() {
        this.output = this.input + ' (processed)';
      }
    });
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

In Chrome Dev and Canary the processed output is never displayed. I've used the debugger to see that inputChanged does fire on the my-processor element, but my-app never gets the updated output value.

In Chrome 34, Safari and Firefox everything works as expected and the processed output is displayed as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the warning in the console, it's important that the the `my-processor` definitions comes prior to `my-app` that uses it.  `my-processor` needs to be registered first for the bindings to be picked up properly.

http://jsbin.com/xovegoga/3/edit

Comment: Oh wow, it had been staring me in the face. Not sure why my brain flagged that as not an important warning. Thanks!